# How to force a redraw within a loop?

Tags: scala, processing

I am using processing within Scala (although I don't think this is really relevant to my question).

I am constructing a searchtree within a loop that runs until a valid path has been found. That can take a few seconds and I would like to draw the graphical representation of the tree while it is being build so the user can see something is happening.

I tried to solve this by calling `redraw()` within the loop but that doesn't work. I guess because `redraw()` doesn't force a redraw but only sets a flag that a redraw should be done.

So is there a way I can force a redraw or how would you normally solve such a problem?

Comment: on what/where are you drawing? Swing?

Comment: No. I am just overwriting the `draw()` method of PApplet

Comment: I'm guessing your searchtree is happening in the draw() and some loops there might prevent the rest of the animation thread from running. How about running the search tree in a separate thread ?

Comment: No. The loop runs within the `keyTyped` method of PApplet. And yes, the draw isn't being called because the whole Thread is being blocked by my loop. That's why I would have wanted something like `forceRedraw()`. But since that does not exist in Processing a second Thread will probably be the next best solution. thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@George Profenza's comment is correct.  Processing tasks all happen on the Animation Thread.  Any tasks you execute within draw() will lock that thread until they complete.  If you want to update the screen while a task is executing, either run the task on a separate thread (beyond the scope of the Processing API, you have to use Java for this), or break the task up into segments and let the draw() method return at the end of each segment so PApplet can render to the screen.

Comment: Well the loop actually runs in the overwritten `keyTyped` method. And of course I know why the "normal" draw isn't being called. That's why I asked if there was a way that I could force a redraw because that would have been the easiest and cleanest solution. But I guess that simply can't be done with Processing. So I guess running the loop in a separate thread will be the best solution. Splitting the code into multiple smaller loops processed in the `draw` method is actually the solution I am using now but I think it's not a very elegant one.

Comment: it's not particularly elegant, but that's the "normal" way to run asynchronous updates in single-threaded programs.  same thing with Flash, e.g. http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2581.  but since Processing is Java, you can spin off a separate thread to build your searchtree.

Comment: btw, the keyTyped method is called from within PApplet.handleDraw(), which is essentially the main loop, aka Processing's draw(), aka the Animation Thread's run() method.  so your searchtree build more or less *is* happening within draw().  http://code.google.com/p/processing/source/browse/trunk/processing/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java